# Update Cell's Constraints after Editing Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I am having an issue with auto layout where upon entering editing mode for my table view, the cell's labels get updated to fit into a small space (This looks fine). The problem is that upon exiting editing mode, the label's constraints are not updated to fit to the larger contentView. Here is my attempt at fixing this. Anyone have any ideas how I should do this?

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `layoutIfNeeded` :

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```